# Wrap a C header in C++

Tags: c++

Suppose I have some C code that I want to wrap using C++ without exposing the C code to the user.

My first attempt was to manually include all headers used in the C code before including the C headers inside a namespace, to hide them from the global scope. This seemed to initially work and compile, however, after trying to use some of the defined structures, I got compilation and linking errors since it couldn't find their definitions.

So my question is, either how do I make the above work, or how else do I make my wrapper in a way not to expose the C code to the user of the C++ headers.

I should mentioned, that I need the structures and other types in my declarations, so I can't include the header in the cpp file only, for example:

```cpp
class Wrapper {
    c_struct* _internal;

public:
    void proxy() {
        c_function(this->_internal);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use an opaque type pointer, so you can include the C headers in the cpp file only.

Comment: @Eljay by opaque do you mean `void*`? Is there a way to not have to do that? And is there a way to only expose part of the C header outside, like types only?

Comment: Example for Xyzzy C code:  `struct xyzzy_automobile; using xyzzy_automobile_ptr = xyzzy_automobile*;` Now you can use `xyzzy_automobile_ptr` as an opaque pointer to your C++ code, and is the bridging pointer used by your C++ Xyzzy interface code to the Xyzzy C library.  It acts as a "firewall" between your general C++ code and the sequestered Xyzzy C library (where your cpp file that implements the Xyzzy bridge uses it as the glue).

Comment: It doen't have to be `void*`, it can be a "real" type. Like `struct Secret; Secret* CreateOne(); void HandleIt(Secret*);` and then define the struct in your cpp file (or import the C data there).

Comment: @BoP, Elijay, from what I understood, you suggested to declare a struct in C++ and expose it outside. Then in the cpp file include C code and somehow bind the declared struct to the C struct? I don't think I understood you correctly. I either get "conflicting declarations", or "cannot convert [c++ struct] to [c struct]"

Comment: The opaque C++ pointer "binds" to the C struct through your bridge code.  There will be `reinterpret_cast` involved.  Your bridge code acts as a firewall, so the C headers are isolated from the rest of your code (other than the bridging code itself).

Comment: @Guiorgy the class declaration is fine, you just need to move the definition of `void proxy()` to implementation file. (and forward declare `c_struct`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [pimpl idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) to hide all the C headers and `struct`s inside your `.cpp` file.

Example `.hpp` file:

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <memory>

class Wrapper {
public:
    Wrapper();
    Wrapper(const Wrapper&);
    Wrapper(Wrapper&&) noexcept = default;
    Wrapper& operator=(const Wrapper&);
    Wrapper& operator=(Wrapper&&) noexcept = default;
    ~Wrapper() = default;

    void proxy();

private:
    struct internal_type;                       // forward declaration
    std::unique_ptr<internal_type> m_internal;  // pointer to implementation
};
```

Example `.cpp` file:

```cpp
#include "Wrapper.hpp"
//#include the C header here.
/*
I assume it contains declarations like below:
struct c_struct;

struct c_struct* c_struct_create();
struct c_struct* c_struct_clone(struct c_struct*); // if it can be cloned
void c_struct_destroy(struct c_struct*);
void c_function(struct c_struct*);
*/
#include <utility>

// the definition of Wrapper::internal_type may inherit from c_struct - or
// use composition like below:
struct Wrapper::internal_type {
    internal_type() : handle(c_struct_create()) {}
    internal_type(const internal_type& rhs) : handle(c_struct_clone(rhs.handle)) {}
    internal_type(internal_type&& rhs) noexcept :
        handle(std::exchange(rhs.handle, nullptr)) {}
    internal_type& operator=(const internal_type& rhs) {
        if(this == &rhs) return *this;
        if(handle) c_struct_destroy(handle);
        handle = c_struct_clone(rhs.handle);
        return *this;
    }
    internal_type& operator=(internal_type&& rhs) noexcept {
        std::swap(handle, rhs.handle);
        return *this;
    }
    ~internal_type() { if(handle) c_struct_destroy(handle); }

    void proxy() { c_function(handle); }

private:
    c_struct* handle;
};

// default constructor
Wrapper::Wrapper() : m_internal(std::make_unique<internal_type>()) {}

// copy constructor
Wrapper::Wrapper(const Wrapper& o)
    : m_internal(std::make_unique<internal_type>(*o.m_internal)) {}

// copy assignment operator
Wrapper& Wrapper::operator=(const Wrapper& rhs) {
    *m_internal = *rhs.m_internal;
    return *this;
}

// the proxy functions just forward to the internal implementation
// in internal_type:
void Wrapper::proxy() {
    m_internal->proxy();
}
```

Comment: I am getting `invalid use of incomplete type ‘c_struct’ {aka ‘struct _c_struct’} @ struct Wrapper::internal_type : c_struct {};` ("c_struct" is itself a forward declaration of "_c_struct"). Any idea why? Calling the C functions directly compiles and runs fine with g++

Comment: @Guiorgy You need the definition of `c_struct` for this to work, so, in the `.cpp` file, include the header that defines `c_struct`.

Comment: I have already included the header with the line `typedef struct _c_struct c_struct;`. If I have to include the header with the `_c_struct` as well, the C code is a statically compiled library (`*.a`), the headers in the "include" directory do NOT include the header where `_c_struct` is defined.

Comment: @Guiorgy You need the definition and you have it in the `include` directory used to compile the static library. Use the same header file here. If you actually _don't_ access the members of `_c_struct` in your code, then make it a `_c_struct*` instead.

Comment: I took that header from the C source, removed all extra includes and put it among my source files, and it compiled and run. But why? Also, doesn't this mean that if the C structure is modified and I recompile both C and C++, the C++ compilation would fail, since that header file I copied is outdated? How should this be maintained?

Comment: also compilation fails if I name my structure the same as the C structure, and/or if I put the forward declaration into a separate header so I can use it in several places. Is this expected behavior?

Comment: @Guiorgy _"But why?"_ - It seems it only needed the definition of `_c_struct`. _"recompile"_ - Yes, you must use the same definition of `_c_struct` so it's best to leave it in the static library source, so that if the header is updated, it will automatically be updated when you build your C++ wrapper-library. _"compilation fails" - The forward declaration of `Wrapper::internal_type` only makes sense in `Wrapper` since the actual definition is hidden within the `.cpp` file and since the class is a nested class. You could however forward declare a free `internal_type` unlimited number of times.

Comment: @Guiorgy Also: Are you accessing the members of `_c_struct` inside your C++ code or is that type actually meant to be opaque in itself?

Comment: I tried accessing a member of the struct and got "incomplete type", which makes sense since this struct holds internal context that needs to be passed to all C functions. The header even has "private" in the name, hence it's not normally exposed. While it could be helpful to modify the internal context from C++ without going through the C functions, it could potentially lead to problems if I'm not careful, and I don't yet have the need to. The problem is that trying to wrap the struct in a `unique_ptr` causes `error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type`. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Guiorgy After you included the internal header that defined `c_struct` you must have been able to tamper with the members - but - it sounds more and more like it's supposed to be an opaque handle to something, much like a `FILE*` like `stdout`. If that's the case, you'll just have to settle for the forward declaration of `c_struct` and use `c_struct` references (in the form of pointers or references) inside the C++ implementation. In that case, you shouldn't use a `unique_ptr` without a _Deleter_, which is the function that free's this resource.

Comment: I did define a Deleter, but even so I'd get the error mentioned above with `unique_ptr` without the internal header. Maybe I could forego smart pointers altogether, but I was hoping I could use them. Even if I used a raw pointer to this opaque handle, how do I forward declare without using the internal headers? Since from your explanation I have to extend that handle (`struct Wrapper::internal_t : c_handle_t {};`) which won't compile without those headers (invalid use of incomplete type).

Comment: Also, since my structure extends the internal but still technically is a different type, I guess I'd have to case the internal to my struct. Can there any alignment differences between C and C++ if I just copy the internal C headers and compile them as C++?

Comment: @Guiorgy If you want to make it work without using the internal header (and definition of `c_struct`), you can not inherit from it or use anything but pointers and references. The C library is most probably contain both the function that creates and returns a `c_struct*` and also a function to free all resources assosiated with it.

Comment: Yes, it does have those functions. However, the main question was "how do I use that header in my code without exposing it (without using it in a header)?" I need pointers to the internal types as my class members, and if possible, I wanted to use smart pointers. So far the only 2 ways I see are: Either forward declaring using the internal headers (your method), which works with smart pointers, or maybe using generic `void*` pointer in my class and casting it to the internal type every time (haven't tested this yet). Not a big fan of option 2 though. What else can I do?

Comment: @Guiorgy You only need to include it in the `.cpp` file. You _can_ use a `void*` in the header file or wrap the `c_struct*` in a class if you'd like. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/q466xbx84) - this also makes it possible to use a `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @Guiorgy I updated the answer to use `c_struct` as an opaque type since it seems like that's the way it was intended to be used.